# Golang: Method expressions instances of Object

Tags: oop, object, methods, go

I'm trying to build a variadic function for a constructor in golang and I've ran into an interesting issue. This function is working...

```
package main
import "fmt"
type person struct {
    name string
}

// This is working, but a really Not how I want to do this
func personConstructor(params ...string) person {
    name := "Unnamed Person" // Default name
    if len(params) > 0 {
        name = params[0]
    }
    return person{name: name}
}

func main() {
    bob := personConstructor("Bob")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dcAdHEQtYz

And yet this, isn't.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct {
    name string
}

// This isn't working
func (p person) constructor(params ...string) person {
    name := "Unnamed Person" // Default name
    if len(params) > 0 {
        name = params[0]
    }
    return person{name: name}
}
func main() {
    bob := person.constructor("Bob")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/YiTQctu-1A

Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: Could you explain please?        
https://play.golang.org/p/hwgVR0qGuh

Comment: Using a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) in general is extremely uncommon, and almost never used for a constructor. Using a regular function as a constructor is idiomatic and would be what most programmers expect.

Comment: The answers are right, but to put it another way, your method is declared to _take an already-existing `person`_. The standard thing is, as JimB says, `newPerson` returning a `person` or `*person`--`godoc` is smart enough to recognize that that is, in effect, a constructor, and group it under the type. It's not uncommon to have multiple constructors with different params like `compress/zlib`'s `NewWriter` and `NewWriterLevel`, and it's also alloed to just let callers initialize with a struct literal (e.g. `http.Server`) or the zero value (`sync.Mutex`, `bytes.Buffer`, `bufio.Reader`, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The introduction in the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1) provides a concise answer to your question.

> Go does not have classes. However, you can define methods on types.

Your examples assume that the `constructor` function is defined on the definition of the `person` struct. This is not the case. A method operates on an instance of a type referred to as a [*receiver*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations). A constructor is not possible in this mechanism. The established pattern within the Go community is to use a factory function to initialize a struct and is exemplified in your first function definition.

The second example provided is failing because `constructor` is expecting to be called on an instance of a person which is undefined. If you construct a new instance of a `person` struct the function behaves as expected.

```
// https://play.golang.org/p/5XDGSTMVj9

func (p person) constructor(params ...string) person {
    name := "Unnamed Person" // Default name
    if len(params) > 0 {
        name = params[0]
    }
    return person{name: name}
}

func main() {
    // Lets define a new instance of a person struct
    p := person{}

    // The function, when called on a instance, works as expected
    bob := p.constructor("Bob")

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", bob)
}
```

This illustrates that methods are attributed to an instance of a particular type.

Comment: A slightly different way to solve it. See https://play.golang.org/p/cdYQB26my1z.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem has nothing to do with variadics.

You need to read and learn about method expressions :

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions

```
package main

type person struct {
    name string
}

func (p person) constructor(params ...string) person {
    name := "Unnamed Person" // Default name
    if len(params) > 0 {
        name = params[0]
    }
    return person{name: name}
}
func main() {
    // THIS WORKS
    person.constructor(person{},"Bob")
}
```

This compiles but it makes very little sense to do that in your case. the constructor function expect a person receiver. Whether you put it before like

like `person{}.constructor("bob")` or after like `person.constructor(person{},"bob")` doesn't matter. constructor expects a  person receiver . constructor method is not a "field of some person namespace", this isn't javascript.

If you want to write a constructor function write a factory without a receiver

```
func NewPerson(params...string)*Person{
   // code
}
```

that's the idiomatic way to do that in Go.

I suggest you to go through the spec once at least.